# Why can I not use string.length here?

Tags: c++

OK, I am in a class now that I am taking in C++. It is basic and I am still new. I have a quick question about the string.length() function. Can you compare this for an integer value inside of a if statement? So, if I did

```
 if(string.length() = 20)
{
cout << "IT VWERKS" << endl;
}
```

would I get an answer? I tried doing this for a program I was working on and it would not work. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: s/`if(string.length() = 20)`/`if(string.length() == 20)`

Comment: There isn't enough information here. Ideally we'd love to see a [mcve]. We have no idea what `string` is, but presumably it's declared as `std::string string` (and hopefully without a `using namespace std;`). When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the code compiles and runs, but doesn't print what you expect, or does it not compile?

Answer (score 2):

You are using assigment operator `=` inside `if` instead of conditional `==` . so change your code as following .It will work.

```
if(string.length() == 20)
{
cout << "IT VWERKS" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm waiting for OP's response: "thanks it vwerks"

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this it to use the comparison operator (==). In this case, replace the first line with:

```
if (string.length() == 20)
```

By doing `string.length() = 20` you are trying to assign the value 20 to the result of the function `length()`, and that is not possible. By replacing the operator `=` with `==` you are comparing both values. Once they match, the code inside the if statement is executed.